# Can I ensure that one of my Spring ApplicationListeners gets executed last?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, event-handling

I have several services that are listening for Spring events to make changes to my underlying data model.  These all work by implementing `ApplicationListener<Foo>`.  Once all of the `Foo` listeners modify the underlying data model, my user interface needs to refresh to reflect the changes (think `fireTableDataChanged()`).

Is there any way to ensure that a specific listener for `Foo` is always last?  Or is there any way to call a function when all other listeners are done?  I'm using annotation based wiring and Java config, if that matters.

Comment: Can you try implementing [`Ordered`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) in each of your listeners and adjust order appropriately?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz That looks promising, I'll try it in a second.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz care you put that in an answer so I can give you credit for it?  That worked great!

Comment: Done, glad I could help. Can you make sure I haven't messed up the order (lowest goes first, not last)?

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz Yes, lowest integer is highest priority. Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE is Integer.MAX_VALUE.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

All your beans implementing `ApplicationListener` should also implement [`Ordered`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/Ordered.html) and provide reasonable order value. The lower the value, the sooner your listener will be invoked:

```
class FirstListener implements ApplicationListener<Foo>, Ordered {
    public int getOrder() {
        return 10;
    }
    //...
}

class SecondListener implements ApplicationListener<Foo>, Ordered {
    public int getOrder() {
        return 20;
    }
    //...
}

class LastListener implements ApplicationListener<Foo>, Ordered {
    public int getOrder() {
        return LOWEST_PRECEDENCE;
    }
    //...
}
```

Moreover you can implement [`PriorityOrdered`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/PriorityOrdered.html) to make sure one of your listeners is always invoked first.

Comment: Is it possible that order is ignored for auth event listeners? I had `CustomAuthListener implements ApplicationListener<AbstractAuthenticationEvent>, Ordered`, but the `return LOWEST_PRECEDENCE` was never called. Luckily I just had to listen to `InteractiveAuthenticationSuccessEvent` instead of `AuthenticationSuccessEvent` to fix my problem.

Comment: i wish i have found this answer on time. So remember ALL of the beans should implement Ordered. Otherwise the will be executed after the ordered once even after the LOWEST_PRECEDENCE Bean